# urllib2.urlopen - error opening url

Tags: python, python-3.3

I have the following written in wing101 and python 3.3.2

```
def open_page(url):
    """Open the URL string given and return its contents as file."""
    page = None
    increment_num_calls()
    cont = False
    while not cont:
        try:
            page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
            cont = True
        except urllib2.URLError as e:
            print "Warning: Url load error " + str(e) + " for url " + url
            #if not hasattr(e, "code"):
            #    raise
            if hasattr(e, "code") and e.code == 401:
                return None
            time.sleep(TIME_DELAY_PAGE_RETRY)
            return None
        except httplib.BadStatusLine:
            return None
    return page
```

Can anyone help me figure out the bug the error says

```
print "Warning: Url load error " + str(e) + " for url " + url
```

If you want to see any more of the program let me know and I can post it.

Comment: Please don't add your email and that answers be sent there to your  question. That's not how SO works.

Comment: please post the actual error

Comment: Im using version 3.3.2 of python

Comment: Srsly -5 votes? -3 is more than enough ppl. The guy is new here.

Comment: @RickyDaniels `print` is a function in py3.x. Secondly I don't think `urllib2` works in py3.x.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhh, so should I just use py2.x.?

Comment: in py3, use parenthesis like this `print("Warning: Url load error " + str(e) + " for url " + url)`

Comment: Would this work in python portable v2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print works differently in Python 3

Try changing

```
print "Warning: Url load error " + str(e) + " for url " + url
```

to

```
print('Warning: Url load error {} for url {}'.format(e, url))
```